# How can I add trailing zeros to timestamp cells in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In my particular case, I inherited a Google Sheet which has a column of timestamps in the format "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"

However, some of the cells do not have the seconds place despite the format I designated (i.e. hh:mm instead of hh:mm:ss).

How do I add these zeros while maintaining the "timestamp" nature of the cell and not converting it to a string (if adding zeros will make it a string at all)?

Comment: If it did not change when you changed the format, it is already text and you will need to parse the string to make it a true date then you can apply the format.

Comment: @ScottCraner How can I do that automatically? It's a rather large spreadsheet.

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet including your issue? And, if you can do, please also include your expected result.